# ScrollView stacked with another page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

The issue is the background of my scrollview is somewhat have pretty same content as my scroll view. i have try looking but can't found the problem, because every place tell that i just have to place the content into the scrollview. Please Help!

[The design of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isvG9.jpg)

This is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/category_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/category_rv">

                <include layout="@layout/horizontal_scroll_layout" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LinearLayout">

                <include layout="@layout/sliding_ad_layout" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/LinearLayout1">

                <include layout="@layout/grid_product_layout" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put recyclerview and scrollview into nestedscrollview

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add constraints to your scroll view, not to LinearLayout

```
 <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/category_rv">
```